# NullPointerException at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.inTransaction - Android Room

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

In the unit testing test proyect im trying to query the entity `EndPoint` but i got this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.inTransaction(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:100)
    at androidx.room.InvalidationTracker.syncTriggers(InvalidationTracker.java:480)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:353)
    at com.mypackged.data.dao.ConfigurationDao_Impl.setUpdateEndPointConfig(ConfigurationDao_Impl.java:120)
    at com.mypackged.business.server.ServicioGeneralTests.test_just_run_please(ServicioGeneralTests.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Here is the code im trying to test using `MockitoJUnitRunner`:

```
    @Test
    public void test_just_run_please() throws InterruptedException {

        assertNotNull(context);
        CIDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(context, CIDatabase.class, CIDatabase.DB_NAME)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        assertNotNull(db);

        ConfigurationDao configdao = db.getConfiguracionDao();
        assertNotNull(configdao);

        EndPointConfig endPointConfig1 = new EndPointConfig();
        endPointConfig1.setUrl("url");
        configdao.setUpdateEndPointConfig(endPointConfig1); // <--- NullPointerException here

        EndPointConfig endPointConfig = configdao.getEndpointConfig();
        assertNull(endPointConfig);


    }
```

This is the entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "endpoint_config")
public class EndPointConfig {


    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "url")
    private String url;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface ConfigurationDao {

    @Insert(entity = EndPointConfig.class, onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    void setUpdateEndPointConfig(EndPointConfig endPointConfig);
    // .. more methods
}
```

Database :

```
@Database(entities = {TitularCuenta.class, Familiar.class, Parentesco.class, AppConfiguration.class, EndPointConfig.class} , version = 2)
public abstract class CIDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "please_work_database";

    public abstract ConfigurationDao getConfiguracionDao();
    // more dao methods...
}
```

Here the gradle dependencies:

```
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:2.2.4"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:2.2.4"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

If i navigate to the `androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.inTransaction` method here is the line that is throwing the error:

```
@Override
public boolean inTransaction() {
    return mDelegate.inTransaction();
}
```